# How to retrieve the most frequent value of a column for a specific ID in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to fetch the most frequent value from a SQLite 3 database table for each specific *ID* (which is the *ID* of a company). I have tried with `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` as well as with `COUNT()` function.

```
SELECT company_id, max(car) 
FROM car_orders 
GROUP by company_id
ORDER by max(car)
```

For a specific *company_id* (9) I am expecting 'Audi' to be in result but this is not the case as its 'Volkswagen' (which is wrong)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your question is confusing because you mention `id`, but then have `company_id` in the query.

Comment: Im really sorry for this. Instead of ID it should be company_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your attempts, consider joining two aggregates that calculates `COUNT` per car and company and `MAX` of same counter per company. Below uses [CTE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) introduced in SQLite in version 3.8.3, released in [February 2014](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_3.html).

```
WITH cnt AS ( 
   SELECT company_id, car, COUNT(*) AS car_count
   FROM car_orders 
   GROUP by company_id, car
),
 max_cnt AS (
   SELECT cnt.company_id, MAX(cnt.car_count) as max_count
   FROM cnt
   GROUP BY cnt.company_id
)

SELECT cnt.company_id, cnt.car
FROM cnt
INNER JOIN max_cnt
  ON cnt.company_id = max_cnt.company_id
  AND cnt.car_count = max_cnt.max_count
```

Comment: Its working now. But still thanks a lot for the solution. Now Im facing a problem where I have to solve a sql subquery statement since the code cant be run on Python. Im getting "OperationalError, near SELECT"-error

Comment: Without your full Python code block, I cannot know for certain how that error is raised. If you are passing this entire SQL statement including `WITH` inside a `cursor.execute()` it should work. Check `sqlite3.sqlite_version` (assuming you `import sqlite3`) and see if the version is above 3.8.3. that supports CTE.

Answer (score 1):

In the more recent versions of SQLite, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT cc.*
FROM (SELECT company_id, car, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM car_orders
      GROUP by company_id, car
     ) cc
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

In earlier versions, it is a little more complicated:

```
WITH cc as (
      SELECT company_id, car, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM car_orders
      GROUP by company_id, car
     )
SELECT cc.*
FROM cc
WHERE cc.cnt = (SELECT MAX(cc2.cnt)
                FROM cc cc2
                WHERE cc2.company_id = cc.company_id
               );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was really cool. It actually now gives me the correct result. Once again thanks a lot. I just realized that I need to keep on practicing on my SQL skills to catch up!